# Is there a way for a derived implementation of a base function to access a class where base is a friend?

Tags: c++

Here is my issue. I have a container which takes in a pointer to the base class. When the container calls a certain method declared virtual, the derived classes can modify a pointer to the container, but only the base is a friend and since the container is compiled as a dll, it is not convenient to add friend Derived; to the container for each derived class. What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Some example code showing what you are trying to do and what doesn't work would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Friendship is not inherited.

You have at least two options:

- Change the "container" to expose an interface that the derived classes can use
- Have the base class expose an interface to any classes derived from it

Without more details it's hard to tell, but it sounds like this architecture has rather poor encapsulation.